# Postgres 40001 Exception Conditional Insert

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, postgresql-9.6, mvcc

I have 3 tables, `A`,`B` and `C`. A function `actOnABC(i)` which is a read only operation on the tables:

```
IF actOnABC(i) = 0 THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Message';
ELSE
    INSERT INTO TABLE B VALUES(...);
END IF;
```

I am running this with Spring JDBC, Transaction Isolation level set to SERIALIZABLE.

As the load/number of concurrent transactions increase, I get the Exception with message:

> ERROR:  could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies
>   among transactions.

Lets say, I have two concurrent Transactions `T1` and `T2`. `T1 and T2` both are attempting to insert. If say, `T1` is successful in making the insert first into table `B`, then potentially the result of `actOnABC(i)` which was already evaluated by `T2` could change. Hence `T2` will throw an exception.

Have I understood the situation correct? Also, is there any way I can combine the `actOnABC(i)` call with the `INSERT` statement so as to avoid this race condition? I did think of using transaction level locks. But I am afraid that won't work as I have other stored procedures actively updating the Tables `A`, `B` and `C`.

Is there a smarter way to deal with the situation?

EDIT: Some more information on the stored procedure `actOnABC()`. This procedure returns an integer which is calculated as below.

```
SELECT count(*) into tmp_a from (... access tables..);
SELECT count(*) into tmp_b from (... access tables...);
return tmp_a - tmp_b;
```

Comment: What does `actOnABC` return and why can you put it into a where clause?

Answer (score 1):

Please see [PostgreSQL Documentation, Chapter 13. Concurrency Control, 13.2. Transaction Isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/transaction-iso.html) for both Repeatable Read and Serializable isolation level descriptions:

> Applications using this level must be prepared to retry transactions due to serialization failures.

It's impossible to do within a Postgres function - the client application needs to do this retrying. And in Serializable isolation level this retrying is required even for read-only transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put it into a `INSERT INTO .. SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO b (a,b,c)
  SELECT a,b,c
  FROM ( VALUES
    (...)
  ) AS t(a,b,c)
  WHERE actOnABC(i) = 0;
```

Comment: I have tried this unsuccessfully. Let me update my original post to give more information about the stored procedure `actOnABC()`

Comment: Let me try out your edited version..

Comment: Unfortunately this does not appear to work either. Note that there could be independent transactions modifying tables `A`,`B` and `C`. So its not just this insert statement which happens concurrently, but there are other transactions which could be modifying tables `A`, `B` and `C` concurrently.